# Python: Writing variables to a file in a specific way

Tags: python, variables, tkinter

So i want the user to select a file and a folder. The file will be moved to said folder, now i want to write those variables (x and y) with their value (the path)  into another file.py with the `shutil.move` module in it as shown below. I am however lost at how I can get the part within `shutil.move`, the variables x and y, to act as variables and thus write the path instead of the letter into the file.py. Is there a way within `f.write` to do this or should I use something else?

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfilename, askdirectory
from tkinter.messagebox import showerror
import shutil


X = askopenfilename(filetypes=(("All files", "*.*"),
                               ("HTML files", "*.html;*.htm"),
                               ("Template files", "*.tplate")))

Y = askdirectory()


f = open("OperatorTest.py", "w")
f.write('shutil.move(X, Y)' )
```

Comment: It's just a string; use one of the many string interpolation or formatting methods in Python.

Comment: If you want that to be a runnable python script, it should include `import shutil\n` before the move.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

```
f.write('shutil.move({0}, {1})'.format(X, Y))
```